DBT unit test - how many rows are returned in Expected
I have a question about unit testsI have a process that takes multiple rows and results in 1 row.  When I run the test, I get the desired values, but 2 rows are returned. I did not find anything in the docs whether this is expected, or whether my aggregation has a bug and it is returning duplicate rows. Simplified code and terminal printout below.
  - name: test_multiple_rows
    model: mrt__2
    given:
      - input: ref('mrt__1')
        rows:
          - { id: 1, amount: 2 }
          - { id: 1, amount: 3 }

    expect:
      rows:
        - { id: 1, total_result: 5 }

07:49:09  Failure in unit_test agg_test (models/_properties.yml)
07:49:09    

actual differs from expected:

@@ ,ID,PRICE_RESULT
+++,1    ,Decimal('5.0')
+++,1    ,Decimal('5.0')
---,1    ,Decimal('5.0')

currently I set up expect to expect 2 rows.
